# Ajax Login for lecturers and student

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to create a login system that takes the user's input(username and password), retrieves it and then input the session data into a new table(tbl_sessions) and then redirect the user based on an attribute in the user's table called personcode(000000 for lecturer and 111111 for students)...I figured I need to chain two ajax requests. One to retrieve the result (from **test.php** which sends the session data as JSON) and the other ajax to **insSession.php** which inserts the session data into the table and returns a JSON object(i passed jd as parameter).......my code works!! well sort of firstly, I can't receive JSON data from the ajax call **insSession.php**(I tried json_decode maybe I'm using it wrongly)so I just bypassed it and used $_SESSION and return a JSON the second problem I'm facing is that if I make an ajax request, my browser refreshes please I need help

1. how do I send data from the first ajax call (var a1) to the 2nd(var a2)
2. how can I successfully redirect the user after the 2nd call without the browser refreshing?

below are the relevant documents

#### HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<!---->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/test.js"></script>
<script src="js/functions.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Optional Bootstrap theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link href="css/design.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


</head>
<body>
<!-- container tag-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-5  col-md-offset-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 login-panel">
        <!--<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4  login_panel">-->
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="login-form">
            <h4 class="text-center panel-heading">Login<!--<small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></small>--></h4>
            <hr>

                <div class="alert alert-danger user-empty" style="display:none">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                <strong>Warning!</strong> Username field is empty.
                </div>
                <!-- end of user-empty -->
                <div class="alert alert-danger pass-empty" style="display:none">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                <strong>Warning!</strong> Password field is empty.
                </div>
                <!-- end of pass-empty-->
                <div class="alert alert-danger both-empty" style="display:none">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                <strong>Warning!</strong> Both fields are empty.
                </div>
                <!--end of both-empty-->
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 " >
                        <div class="input-group form-group">
                            <!--<div class="input-group">-->
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user "></span></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
                            <!--</div>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2  ">

                            <div class="input-group form-group ">
                            <!--<div class="form-group">-->
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                            <!--</div>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 sign-in " type="submit">Sign In <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i></button>
                    </div>
               </div><!-- End of row -->        
            </form>
        <!--</div>--><!--end of login_panel-->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div><!-- end of row-->
</div><!-- end of container-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### functions.js

```
//function that runs a check on login variables
function input_Check(a,b){
    /**
    Where a = username 
    b = password
    **/

            //to specify the missing input, check if it's the username field, password or both
            if(a =="" && b!="")
            {

                $(".user-empty").fadeIn();
                return false;
            }
            else if(a !="" && b =="")
            {
                $(".pass-empty").fadeIn();
                return false;
            }
            else if(a!="" && b!="")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                $(".both-empty").fadeIn();;
                return false;
            }



    }
```

#### AjAX CALL

```
    enter cod// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(e)
{

    $(".sign-in").click(function(){

        //Login Variables
        var username = $(".username").val();//"ayaradua"
        var password = $(".password").val();//Password12

        //Setup login data structure
        var login_Data=
        {
            'key':"Login",
            'username': username,
            'password': password        
        }

    //If the Input isnt empty, make the Ajax call
    if(input_Check(username,password)== true)//you can remove this if statement
        {

            var a1= $.ajax({
             data:login_Data,
             type:"POST",
             url: './php/test.php',
             dataType: 'json',
             beforeSend: function()
                {
                        $(".sign-in").text("connecting...");
                },
         }),
    a2 = a1.then(function(data) {
             // .then() returns a new promise
                 return $.ajax({
                 url: './php/insSession.php',
                 //type:"POST",
                 //dataType: 'json'
                 //data: {'user_Id':data.user_Id,

             });
             //return    $.getJSON('./php/insSession.php');
         });//end of a2

    //i user this alert to confirm if data has been received
    a1.done(function(data,textStatus,xhr){
        alert(data.user_Id+data.session_Id+data.date);
        });
    //after the promise is returned, check the personcode to determine the user's status and redirect them accordingly
    a2.done(function(jd,textStatus,xhr) {
    if(jd.personcode == 000000)
    {
        window.location.href='./lecturer.php';
        //alert("lecturer");
    }
    else if(jd.personcode==111111)
    {
        window.location.href='./student.php';
        //alert("student");
    }
    else {
        $("hr").append("<p class=\"text-danger text-center\">Sorry Couldn't Login check username and password </p>")};
    });

    a2.fail(function(){
                $("hr").append("<p class=\"text-danger text-center\">Problem with Ajax Call </p>");
                });



        }// end of input_Check if statement






    });//end of click method

});// end of ready functione here
```

#### test.php

```
session_start();
//include relevant files

include("../inc/connect.php");

include("./functions.php");

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{
    $username =$_POST["username"];
    $password= $_POST["password"];

    // Setup Query
    $query = "SELECT Id,firstname,lastname,username,password,personcode FROM tbl_User WHERE `username`=? AND `password`=?";

    // Get instance of statement
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($mysqli);

    // Prepare Query
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query);


    // Bind Parameters [s for string]
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'ss',$username,$password);

      // Execute Statement
       if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
       {


           // Bind results to variable
           mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$Id,$firstname,$lastname,$user,$pass,$personcode);

           // Fetch Value
           $fetch= mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

           $array = array("user_Id"=>$Id,
                        "firstname"=>$firstname,
                        "lastname"=>$lastname,
                        "username"=>$user,
                        "password"=>$pass,
                        "personcode"=>$personcode
                        ); 
            $data = json_encode($array);

            $old_sessionid = session_id();

            session_regenerate_id();

            $new_sessionid = session_id();


            $_SESSION = set_Session($array,$new_sessionid);

            unset($_SESSION["firstname"]);
            unset($_SESSION["lastname"]);
            unset($_SESSION["username"]);
            unset($_SESSION["password"]);

            //array_push($_SESSION,$ses_Data);

            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            $dat=json_encode($_SESSION);

            echo $dat;

          // Close Statement
       mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); 



       }




}
//if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']=='XMLHttpRequest')
//{
/**


    // Setup parameter to be bound into query
    $username =$_POST["username"]; //"ayaradua";
    $password= $_POST["password"];//"Password12";







//}
**/
```

#### insSession.php

```
session_start();
include("../inc/connect.php");
include("../php/functions.php");


    $x = array();
    $session_Var= array_merge($x,$_SESSION);
    //get table columns
    $query = "INSERT INTO `tbl_Session` `user_Id`,`personcode`,`session_Id`,`date`)VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($mysqli);
    if(mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$query))
    {

        // bind parameters for markers 
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ssss",$session_Var['user_Id'],$session_Var['personcode'],$session_Var['session_Id'],$session_Var['date']);

        // execute query 
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
        {
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            $json = json_encode($session_Var);
            echo $json;

        }
        else{
            echo "Sorry didn't execute";

            }
    }
```

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: @JayBlanchard please how can I know my PHP version...sorry I'm a noob :)

Comment: Add this to your PHP to see the version: `echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();`

Comment: @jonmrich i got this Current PHP version: 5.2.6-1+lenny13 will it work?

Answer (score 0):

You may chain the two ajax calls in this way, of course this is not the only way (in this way you have full control on the two ajax calls: the parameters/variables to pass from the first to the second and when to redirect):

```js
$(function () {
  $(".sign-in").click(function (e) {
    //Login Variables
    var username = $(".username").val();//"ayaradua"
    var password = $(".password").val();//Password12

    //Setup login data structure
    var login_Data =
        {
          'key': "Login",
          'username': username,
          'password': password
        }
    //If the Input isnt empty, make the Ajax call
    if (input_Check(username, password) == true)//you can remove this if statement
    {
      $.ajax({
        data: login_Data,
        type: "POST",
        url: './php/test.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function () {
          $(".sign-in").text("connecting...");
        }
      }).done(function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        //{"result":true,"data":{"user_Id":"user_Id","personcode":"personcode","session_Id":"LocalSession_Id","data":"date"}};
        alert(data.user_Id + data.session_Id + data.date);
        if (data.result) {
          $.ajax({
            url: './php/insSession.php'
            type:"POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(data.data),
          }).done(function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            if (jd.personcode == 000000) {
              window.location.href = './lecturer.php';
              //alert("lecturer");
            } else if (jd.personcode == 111111) {
              window.location.href = './student.php';
              //alert("student");
            } else {
              $("hr").append("<p class=\"text-danger text-center\">Sorry Couldn't Login check username and password </p>")
            }
            ;
          }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("hr").append("<p class=\"text-danger text-center\">Problem with Ajax Call </p>");
          });
        } else {
          // the first PHP (insSession.php) returned error so...............
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Your insSession.php file need to return always a json value like for instance:

```
{"result":true,"data":{"user_Id":"user_Id","personcode":"personcode","session_Id":"LocalSession_Id","data":"date"}}
```

or

```
{"result":false,"data":null}
```

To achieve this result your insSession.php could be something like:

```js
<?php

$retVal = array( 'result' => false, 'data' => null );

if(result or some computation is true) {
   $data = array( 'user_Id' => 'user_Id', 'personcode' => 'personcode', 'session_Id' => 'LocalSession_Id', 'data' => 'date');
   $retVal = array( 'result' => true, 'data' => $data );    
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $retVal );
?>
```

So whenever you return from this php you have a json object, always valid with a first field containing a value: the oiperation was successfull or not.
If not you cannot continue with the next operation (call the second php) but you need to stop. Instead if you get a successfull result you may see what is changed in the previous done function: now the test is much more easy and the parameters to pass to the second php are very easy.

Comment: please how do i set variables for the 2nd call...i tried JSON.stringifly(data)..also how will i receive it in './php/insSession.php'..again thanks

Comment: Use {var: Val,...} and stringify this json object

Comment: like var obj = {"user_Id":data.user_Id,"personcode":data.personcode,"session_Id":data.session_Id,"data":data.date};        then JSON.stringify(obj)?.........if its correct then how do i use the json decode in the php? mine doesnt read it

Comment: i cudnt get values from the first call it the alert returns "undefined"

Comment: @AkiluAbdulaziz sorry for the delay, Snippet updated. I hope it could be usefull for you